# Weird bug: EditText launches Google Search

Tags: android

I'm doing a very simple test app that uses the text to speech engine and to "say" the text that you put in an EditText. It has an EditText and a Button. However when I try to enter text into the EditText it launches Google Search as soon as I type a letter. ¿Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Update:** When using a physical keyboard it works just fine so I guess it's a problem with the soft keyboard...

XML Code:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/etText" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="top"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
 android:layout_marginRight="2dip" android:inputType="text">
</EditText>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try posting some of you codes.

Comment: There is no code for the EditBox

Comment: You need the code for your edit text box, atleas the XML layout of it

Comment: ok it's this:<EditText android:id="@+id/etText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="top" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" android:layout_marginRight="2dip" android:inputType="text"></EditText>

Comment: You're not calling `startSearch()` or `onSearchRequested()` by accident in your app are you?

Answer (score 1):

Setting`android:inputType="text"` in the layout xml for the EditText and in the Activity calling `editTextFieid.requestFocus()` solved the problem for me. 
This problem only occurs for the first EditText in an Activity. It was the username EditText in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when I had an unused `OnClickListener`.

In refactoring code, I found that I had left an empty `onClickListener` and `onClick` method. Removing the `implements OnClickListener` and method containing `public void onClick(View view)` items, and I never got the search box to appear on my `editText` click-events anymore. It seems odd, but it worked for me!

Also, I removed the following line:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```